# seaborn.lmplot raises ValueError when set both `hue` and `scatter_kws`'s `s`

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot, relplot

This code is provided in the book "Pandas for everyone" (3.4.3.2 Size and Shape).

```py
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.lmplot(
    x='total_bill',
    y='tip',
    data=tips,
    fit_reg=False,
    hue='sex',
    scatter_kws={'s': tips['size'] * 10}
)
plt.show()
```

When I run this code, it results ValueError at [matplotlib/axes/_axes.py line 4508](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/e3fe991d45a3dbdf3afeaf8bd4556980178183eb/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L4508).

> ValueError: s must be a scalar, or float array-like with the same size
> as x and y

This error won't be raised if I omit the `hue` argument. It seems that the data (`tips['total_bill']` and `tips['tip']`) are split by `sex`, but `tips['size']` is not split, so the lengths are different.

How can I manage to plot the figure without error?

**Versions**

- Python 3.7
- matplotlib 3.4.2
- seaborn 0.11.1

Ran on both windows 10 and Google Colab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- As per seaborn issue 2621, [lmplot with scatter_kws or relplot with s: ValueError: s must be a scalar, or float array-like with the same size as x and y](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2621), the seaborn main developer states this should not work with `lmplot` and *alarmed that it's in that book!*.

  - *I believe the reason it stopped "working" is that matplotlib added some input validation to catch cases like this.*
  - `lmplot` draws separate scatterplots for each level of `hue`, but the matplotlib `kwargs` are just passed straight through to scatter, so those vectors are going to have different lengths.
- Using `seaborn 0.11.1` and `matplotlib 3.4.2`

### Use `sns.scatterplot`

```py
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="sex", size='size')
```

[image]

```py
sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="sex", s=tips["size"].mul(20))
```

[image]

### Use `sns.relplot`

```py
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

sns.relplot(data=tips, kind='scatter', x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="sex", size='size')
```

[image]

```py
sns.relplot(data=tips, x='total_bill', y='tip', hue='sex', s=tips['size'].mul(20))
```

[image]